# Wifi Direct Group Owner Address is always 192.168.49.1, UnknownHostExeption

Tags: android, sockets, exception, host, wifi-direct

Was following this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) to connect devices using Wifi direct to send message between two devices (device A with android 4.3 and Device B 7). When I try to connect client (device A) to server (device B) to transfer data using

```
socket.connect(new InetAddress(host, port)), 500);
```

It always gives UnknownHostException.

**P.S -** Device B is groupOwner. (checked using ConnectionInfo). IP address of groupOwner is always 192.168.49.1.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: No, still looking for a headstart!

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure a Wi-Fi Direct connection is established, then the GO automatically runs the DHCP to assign IP addresses to itself (192.168. 49.1/24)